# Does Sphinx ignore end/middle punctation for word/tokens?

Tags: sphinx

So if I index/search for 'Bob' and I have text like:

```
"and sent to Bob, Ted and Alice"
"last one was Bob"
"It was Bob!?"
"I sent it to Robert (Bob)"
```

Is Bob going to be found?

Comment: Is there any reason why you haven't just tested this?

Comment: @SamiLaine I did test except as you know Sphinx can be finicky/confusing so it is not always clear what is going on, I've had mixed results. So I'm just trying to get some confirmation either way, thank you.